# R: Nelder-Mead optimization for nonlinear mixed effects models

Tags: r, optimization, mixed-models, nonlinear-optimization

The data are found [here](https://www.stat.ubc.ca/~lang/Stat527a/aids.dat2)

```
library(nlme)
library(dfoptim)
dat0 <- read.table("aids.dat2",head=T)
dat1 <- dat0[dat0$day<=90, ]   # use only first 90-day data
dat2 <- dat1[!apply(is.na(dat1),1,any),]  # remove missing data 
aids.dat <- groupedData(lgcopy ~ day | patid, data=dat2)
aids.dat$log10copy = log10(aids.dat$lgcopy)

myfun2 <- function(s.p1, s.b1, s.p2, s.b2){
  model = nlme(log10copy ~ exp(p1-b1*day) + exp(p2-b2*day + 1),
               fixed = list(p1 ~ 1, b1 ~ 1, p2 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1),
               random = list(patid = pdDiag(list(p1 ~ 1, b1 ~ 1, p2 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1))),
               start = list(fixed = c(p1 = s.p1, b1 = s.b1, p2 = s.p2, b2 = s.b2)),
               data =aids.dat) 
  return(model$logLik)
}

nmkb(fn = myfun2, par = c(1.13, 0.25, 13.1, 1.3), lower = c(0.8, -0.3, 5, -2), upper = c(1.6, 0.6, 20, 13))
```

I am trying to run a Nelder-Mead optimization algorithm (in the `dfoptim` package) to find good starting values for my nonlinear mixed effects model. My objective function is the `logLik` from my model. I then call `nmkb` where `fn` is my function, `par` are the values of my 4 parameters  with their `lower` and `upper` bounds. However, I am running into the error

```
Error in nlme.formula(log10copy ~ exp(p1 - b1 * day) + exp(p2 - b2 * day +  : 
  argument "s.b1" is missing, with no default
```

Seems to be a syntax issue, but what exactly went wrong here?

Comment: In your function `myfun2`, there should be only one argument, and `s.p1` should be the first element of the argument, `s.b1` should be the second...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myfun2 <- function(p1b1p2b2){
    s.p1 <- p1b1p2b2[1]
    s.b1 <- p1b1p2b2[2]
    s.p2 <- p1b1p2b2[3]
    s.b2 <- p1b1p2b2[4]
    model = nlme(log10copy ~ exp(p1-b1*day) + exp(p2-b2*day + 1),
                 fixed = list(p1 ~ 1, b1 ~ 1, p2 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1),
                 random = list(patid = pdDiag(list(p1 ~ 1, b1 ~ 1, p2 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1))),
                 start = list(fixed = c(p1 = s.p1, b1 = s.b1, p2 = s.p2, b2 = s.b2)),
                 data =aids.dat) 
    return(model$logLik)
}
```